# Sum field value in React from JSON API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this data array retrieved from the database with Axios, I want to return the sum of a field based on some conditions

I already used map() to grab the data from my backend :

// getData.js

```
return (
  <ul>
    {attendance.map(({ _id, name, male }) => {

      return (
        <div key={_id}>
          <br />
          <hr />
          <li>{name}</li>
          {/* the condition is to render only male that are  >= 2 */}
          <li>{male >= 2 ? male : 0}</li>
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </ul>
)
```

//output

```
Joshua Jaccob
2

Fabio Rio
2

Lancelot Abe
2

Bello
0

Becca Andrew
0
```

I want to sum the total male that fit the condition, also
render only those that fit the condition

Comment: What's your question? Does your code not work? It's difficult to tell with this code what the issue is because you haven't provided an example of the data you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You could push all attendances with your condition into a list, then length of the list will be total number.

The last, just render the list.

```
// get all attendances with male >= 2
const list = attendance.filter(({ male }) => {
  return male >= 2;
});

return (
  <div>
    <h3>Total attendances with male >= 2: {list.length}</h3>
    <ul>
//pass in name and _id
      {list.map(({ name,_id }) => {
        return (
          <div key={_id}>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <li>{name}</li>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .filter function to filter the array using the condition then use map to render like below.

```
return (
  <ul>
    {attendance
      .filter(({ male }) => male >=2 )
      .map(({ _id, name, male }) => {
        return (
          <div key={_id}>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <li>{name}</li>
            <li>{male}</li>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </ul>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
attendance.filter((male)=>male>=2)
.map((_id,ind,male)=>{
return (
 //male.length will give you the sum of total male that fill the condition

)
}
```

Array.prototype.filter gives u an array of results which only passes the condition in this case the age>=2